# ◯◯ and ( or 複数）というような条件で調べたいが、or の条件が反映されない

Tags: python, python3

CSV形式のファイルに対して、`◯◯ がある行` and `any()内のどれかの数字があるもの` というようにしたいのだが、`and の前の条件で当てはまるもののみ`、または `◯◯` and `any内の最初の数字だけが該当するもの` というようなコードでしか作成できなかった。

"◯◯" があり 且つ "any内のどれか数字がある行" を探すにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？
おそらくor の条件が反映されてません。

```py
if (("◯◯" in line) and (any(["8847450" or "3625014" or "3625037" or "8831472"])in line)):
```

---

StackOverflowに投稿するのが初めてでコードの質問の仕方も全然わからないものです。
医療機関のためあまり情報は出さないほうが良いかと思っておりましたが程々出します。

orという条件を反映させたいが反映されない。
イメージとしては、SYがある行 且つ その行に AかBかCかDかEの病名がある患者番号を出力するというのが目的です。自分ではorの使い方がまちがっているのではと思ってます。

```
if ("SY") and ("A"or"B"or "C"or"D"or "E")in line:
```

any や 下記のように試しましたが、SY行がある患者番号がSYがある数だけ出力されるだけでした。

```py
if "SY"in line and ("8847450"or"3625014"or "3625037"or"8831472"or
 "8847490"or"8849662"or"8837631"or"8837585"or"8842213"or"8841636"or"8830978"
 or"8840886"or"8840626"or"3627007"or"3671002"or"8833933"
 or"3623046"or"8840647"or"8845932"or"8841160"or"8847607"or"8847668"or"8849687"
 or"8840659"or"8840661"or"8849884"or"8846886"or"8842298"
 in line):
```

---

#### コードの全体

```py
from os import O_EXLOCK
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv

# データセットの読み込み
#f = pd.read_csv('RECEIPTC.UKE', 'r', encoding="shift-jis")
f=open("/Users/RECEIPTC.UKE", encoding="shift-jis")
#'utf-8'

############################################################################
                                                                           #
                        #診療                                              #
############################################################################
#if SY（病名）行　　に000000000がある
#if "SI"(診療行為）行　and"00000000"がある

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
#自発蛍光
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
line_RE = False
line_SY = False
line_SI = False

for line in f:
    # REが出てくるたびに患者名を格納、初期化
    if 'RE' in line:
        name = line.split(',')[13]
        line_RE = True
        line_SY = False
        line_SI = False

    #if SY2（病名）行　　に  等がある      
    if ("SY") and ("8847450"or"3625014"or "3625037"or"8831472"or
    "8847490"or"8849662"or"8837631"or"8837585"or"8842213"or"8841636"or"8830978"
    or"8840886"or"8840626"or"3627007"or"3671002"or"8833933"
    or"3623046"or"8840647"or"8845932"or"8841160"or"8847607"or"8847668"or"8849687"
    or"8840659"or"8840661"or"8849884"or"8846886"or"8842298")in line:
        line_SY  = True  # SYの該当あり判定
        print(name) 
    #自発蛍光　　160199310
    if("SI" and "160199310") in line:
        line_SI = True  # SIの該当あり判定
        #print(name) 
    """"""""""""""""""""""""
    #1879  4699 1221 4213 4687 3190 2982
    #4125 3782 3189 4161 3128
    """"""""""""""""""""""""
    if not (line_SY)  and line_SI :
        #print(name)  # 患者名出力
        """"""""""""""""""""""""
        #1879  4699 1221 4213 4687 3190 2982
        #4125 3782 3189 4161 3128
        """"""""""""""""""""""""
        line_RE = False
        line_SY = False
        line_SI = False
        # 初期化
    #break (breakがあると何も出てこなくなる)
```

---

## 追記

2個あります　　2個目は追加となります

#### 1点目

@oriri   さんのアドバイスを元にコードを編集したのですが
下記コードにて　同じ患者番号が出るのは　該当　のid_list　内の番号に当てはまる番号が２個あるので患者番号も２個でるのでしょうか？
例えば  「 >　」　　の部分なのですが　　2344は　病名（SY行に含まれている数字）に 8831472　が2個ありました（病名をつける際に、右　　左等　修飾コード＋病名になるためです　　例えば　　右という意味の数字、8831472　　　や　　左という意味の数字、8831472　　になるため　　一人の該当患者の　SY行複数個の中に　　　8831472　　が2個あることになります　　　　そのため出力すると　2344が2個出力されるのでしょうか？
しかし   2542  は同じ該当病名の数字がありませんでした　これは、id_list　内の番号にあてはまるものが2つあるからでしょうか？ 　　例えば"8847450","3625014"　　があったため等。

```py
    #if SY2（病名）行　　に  等がある 

    id_list = ["8847450","3625014", "3625037","8831472",
    "8847490","8849662","8837631","8837585","8842213","8841636","8830978"
    ,"8840886","8840626","3627007","3671002","8833933"
    ,"3623046","8840647","8845932","8841160","8847607","8847668","8849687"
    ,"8840659","8840661","8849884","8846886","8842298"]

    if "SY" in line and any(id in line for id in id_list):
        line_SY  = True  # SYの該当あり判定
        #print(name) 
        #8831472  30件あるが出てこない
        """"""""""""""""""""""""
        #1879
        #3128  3816 4699 3218 2496 4213 4689
        #4687 4626 3870                      >2344 2344 (8831472)
        #                                    >4669 4669 (?)
        #3154 3190 4499 199 3074 2982 4108 
        #                                    >2542 2542 (?)
        #4125 3052 
        #                                    >3879 3879  (#8831472)
        #3782  
        #                                    >3189 3189 (?)
        #4488   
        #                                    >4161 4161  (8834556)
        #2987  3128
        """"""""""""""""""""""""
```

#### 2点目

同じコードを　　例えば　　輻輳のパターン、　自発蛍光　のパターンを下記のように続けて書くと
自発蛍光だけのコードのときは出力されるものが何も出力されない
break を入れましたが意味がなさそうです

```py
############################################################################
                                                                           #
                        #診療                                              #
############################################################################


#####◯◯◯◯◯◯◯◯！！！！輻輳◯◯◯◯◯◯◯◯◯◯◯◯◯◯◯◯◯######
line_RE = False
line_SY = False
line_SI = False
for line in f:
    # REが出てくるたびに患者名を格納、初期化
    if 'RE' in line:
        name = line.split(',')[13]
        line_RE = True
        line_SY = False
        line_SI = False

    #if SY2（病名）行　　に3789001(斜視）等がある       

    id_list = ["3789001","3784001", "8831705","8844716",
    "3673004","8847774","3785017","3795003","3795019","8026003","8845049",
    "8845078","8838065","3785007","3785014","3675013"]

    if "SY" in line and any(id in line for id in id_list):
        line_SY  = True  # SYの該当あり判定
        #print(name) 
        #4357  4358
        #3784001→5件
        #1827  4338  4321 4341 4357 4319 567 4358 387
    if('SI' and '160083810') in line:
        line_SI = True  # SIの該当あり判定
        #print(name) 
        #4338  4321
        #4341  4357 4319  4358 387
        
        #if "SI"(診療行為）行　and"160083810"（輻輳）がある

    if not (line_SY)  and line_SI :
        #print(name)  # 患者名出力
        #4338  4321  4341 4319  387
        line_RE = False
        line_SY = False
        line_SI = False
        # 初期化
    break         
    
 
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
#自発蛍光
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
line_RE = False
line_SY = False
line_SI = False

for line in f:
    # REが出てくるたびに患者名を格納、初期化
    if 'RE' in line:
        name = line.split(',')[13]
        line_RE = True
        line_SY = False
        line_SI = False

    
    
    #if SY2（病名）行　　に  等がある 

    id_list = ["8847450","3625014", "3625037","8831472",
    "8847490","8849662","8837631","8837585","8842213","8841636","8830978"
    ,"8840886","8840626","3627007","3671002","8833933"
    ,"3623046","8840647","8845932","8841160","8847607","8847668","8849687"
    ,"8840659","8840661","8849884","8846886","8842298"]

    if "SY" in line and any(id in line for id in id_list):
        line_SY  = True  # SYの該当あり判定
        #print(name) 
        #8831472  30件あるが出てこない
        """"""""""""""""""""""""
        #1879
        #3128  3816 4699 3218 2496 4213 4689
        #4687 4626 3870                      2344 2344 (8831472)
        #                                    4669 4669 (?)
        #3154 3190 4499 199 3074 2982 4108 
        #                                    2542 2542 (?)
        #4125 3052 
        #                                    3879 3879  (#8831472)
        #3782  
        #                                    3189 3189 (?)
        #4488   
        #                                    4161 4161  (8834556)
        #2987  3128
        """"""""""""""""""""""""
    #自発蛍光　　160199310
    if("SI" and "160199310") in line:
        line_SI = True  # SIの該当あり判定
        print(name) 
    """"""""""""""""""""""""
    #1879  4699 1221 4213 4687 3190 2982
    #4125 3782 3189 4161 3128
    """"""""""""""""""""""""
    if not (line_SY)  and line_SI :
        #print(name)  # 患者名出力
        """"""""""""""""""""""""
        #1221のみになった
        """"""""""""""""""""""""
        #1879  4699 1221 4213 4687 3190 2982
        #4125 3782 3189 4161 3128
        """"""""""""""""""""""""
        line_RE = False
        line_SY = False
        line_SI = False
        # 初期化

    break 
    # (breakがあると何も出てこなくなる)
```

Comment: `line`の型は何ですか？ CSVファイルとの関係は？ (例えば, CSVの 1行分のリストが入ってるとか？) (あるいはもしかして全部の行の全項目が入ってるとか？)
コードの断片ではなく全体示すようにしてください (確認も何もできない)。
あと `or`とか `any` とか使い方間違っています。

Comment: [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/26370) 的なものでは？ 元々は何をしたかったのでしょう？ それの解決策として思い付いたやり方が上手くいかなくて質問になったのでは？ `line`という変数の取り得る値の例をいくつか提示して、それのどの部分がどうなっているかを調べたい/判定したいとかの詳細を`○○`のようなぼかした表現や何を示すのか分からない数字の列挙ではなく、出来るだけ意味や属性も含めて解説/説明するようにして、元々は何をしたかったのかを書いてみてください。

Comment: どういうことについて知りたいのかをはっきりさせるため、知りたい問題をより具体的にしたり、追加の詳細を書き加えたりしてください。現状のままだと何についての質問なのかが分かりづらいです。

Comment: ＠kunif　　コメントありがとうございます　医療機関なので色々伏せてしまったのですが編集しました

Comment: ＠oriri　　コメントありがとうございます　医療機関なので色々伏せてしまったのですが編集しました　　orの使い方が間違っているのは分かっているのですが１週間か２週間ぐらい温めすぎて時間が経ってしまったので今回質問となりました

Comment: 普通は上から順に読むものなので, 上に追記していくと他の人が読みにくくなります。また, 記述する場合適切に Markdown使用してください。[Markdown ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: 22222... の部分は, `if('SI' and '160083810') in line` の `and`演算子の記述が間違っているので正しく指定してください … Bool を 2つ指定して `and`演算子が成り立つところ文字列指定してるので間違った判定になります。するとその後の判定も間違ったものに

Comment: **> 2344** の部分はもう少し詳しくお願いします。(何処から出てきた数値なのか不明)

Comment: @cubick♦     度々編集していただきありがとうございます　　勉強になります　　参考にしながらMarkdownきちんとできるようにします

Comment: 1@oriri  さん　 Markdownについてもリンクを教えていただきありがとうございます　　リンクと　　おそらく@cubick♦　さん　が編集してくれているようで参考に勉強します

if('SI' and '160083810') in line  について等、回答でもコメントしていただきありがとうございます　　　in lineをどちらにもかけないといけないんですね　省略しすぎていました

> 2344 の部分ですが、　　追記１点目の　　　
#4687 4626 3870                      >2344 2344 (8831472)　　の部分が1個目になります
自分の編集で患者番号が重なっているのは右側にまとめ　先頭に＞をつけました
引用のMarkdownのつもりで＞をつけたのですがうまく反映されませんでした

2個目は　　4669 4669 (?)　　の部分です

Comment: @oriri   さんも文章も編集していただきありがとうございました

Comment: **2344** は `name = line.split(',')[13]` で取得した `name` を, *何処かの処理で* `print(name)` 行った結果という意味ですか？
仮にそういう意味なら, 複数ヶ所で表示しているということはないですか？また "RE"が含まれている行でしか `name`を設定していないようなので, "RE"と "SY"などの両方が含まれている行でしか正しい値は表示されないのでは？(データ構造が不明なので適当にしか言えないが)

Comment: @oriri   度々すみません　ありがとうございます　　質問内容が肥大している気がするので別途で質問作ってみます

Answer (score 0):

よく問題を理解できていないだけかもしれませんが、
Pythonのany()はTrueかFalseを返すと思います。
（数字の場合は０以外、Booleanの場合はTrueがリストの中に一つでもあればTrueを返します。）

ですので、上記されているコードでは、

```
any(["8847450" or "3625014" or "3625037" or "8831472"]
```

この部分はTrueしか返っておらず、結果として

```
if (("◯◯" in line) and　(True in line)):
```

となっており、調べたいことに合致していないと思います。

ですので、もし全ての番号がわかっておられるのであれば、
簡単に

```
OKIDs = ["8847450","3625014","3625037","8831472"]
if ("◯◯"in line):
  for id in OKIDs:
    if id in line:
      XXXXXX <- ABCDFさんがやりたいこと
```

しておけば大丈夫なような気がします。
ただし、この場合はlineに”88474501”のような似ている数字が存在する場合も条件に引っかかります。

なので、より細かな条件で調べたいのであれば、
lineの中から、まずは"◯◯"や特定の数字を抜き取ってくる作業を行なった後
if statementにするのがよいかと思いますよ。

Comment: わかりやすい回答ありがとうございます
anyについても間違っているのがわかりました

記載していただいたコードの方法もあるのですね
この方法も組み合わせるとまたいいかもしれませんね

Answer (score 0):

`line`変数が文字列型である場合, `in` 演算は文字列が含まれるかどうかを Boolで返します
(Bool: 真偽値, True あるいは False)

参考: https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations

`and` 演算子や `or` 演算子も, (たいていは) Boolを取り扱い, 結果も Boolです

参考: https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

このため複数の文字列のいずれかが含まれているかどうかは, ジェネレーター式を使って以下のように記述できます

```py
id_list = ["8847450", "3625014", "3625037", "8831472", "8847490",
    "8849662", "8837631", "8837585", "8842213", "8841636", "8830978",
    "8840886", "8840626", "3627007", "3671002", "8833933", "3623046",
    "8840647", "8845932", "8841160", "8847607", "8847668", "8849687",
    "8840659", "8840661", "8849884", "8846886", "8842298"]

line = 'abcd8846886efg'
if any(id in line for id in id_list):
    pass # いずれかの文字が含まれていた場合, の処理

# 質問の条件判断はこんな感じ
if "SY" in line and any(id in line for id in id_list):
    pass #
```

---

pandas使う場合だと, また異なる条件式になります

---

##### 少し追記

リスト内包表記を使い, 番号の文字列が含まれるかどうかのリストを得ることができ, 結果の Boolのリストを `any()` で判定可能

```py
bool_list = [id in line for id in id_list]
print(any(bool_list))
```

[ジェネレーター式](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.7/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)は, `list`ではなく generatorとして使用するもので, (少し動作異なるけど)今回の場合はどちらも結果は同じ

---

##### 追加分: 「自発蛍光」判定

上記にも記したとおり, `and` 演算子や `or` 演算子は(たいてい) Boolを指定するもので, 文字列を指定した場合は 長さ=0 でない限り真となり, この場合演算結果は後に指定されたものが値となり, 意図した判定にはなりません

```py
#自発蛍光　　160199310
#   if("SI" and "160199310") in line:
# この判定はカッコ内が先に行われ, and演算子と文字列で無駄な演算してしまうだけ

# (たぶん)正しくはこのような if文
for line in ['SI', '160199310', '160199310SIO']:
    if "SI" in line and "160199310" in line:
        print(line)
```

また, `break`文は if文のインデントから外れているので, 無条件に行われます

Comment: 回答していただきありがとうございます　　URLも貼っていただきありがとうございます
URL　pythonドキュメントも見たのですがピンときませんでした
oriri　さまのコードを参考に　編集しましたらできたのではないかと思います
重ね重ね申し訳ないのですが質問がありまして
下記コードにて　同じ患者番号が出るのは　該当　のid_list　内の番号に当てはまる番号が２個あるので患者番号も２個でるのでしょうか？

Comment: id_list = ["8847450","3625014", "3625037","8831472",
    "8847490","8849662","8837631","8837585","8842213","8841636","8830978"
    ,"8840886","8840626","3627007","3671002","8833933"
    ,"3623046","8840647","8845932","8841160","8847607","8847668","8849687"
    ,"8840659","8840661","8849884","8846886","8842298"]

    if "SY" in line and any(id in line for id in id_list):
        line_SY  = True  # SYの該当あり判定
        #print(name) 
        #8831472  30件あるが出てこない

Comment: #1879
 #3128  3816 4699 3218 2496 4213 4689
 #4687 4626 3870                      2344 2344 (8831472)
        #                                    4669 4669 (?)
#3154 3190 4499 199 3074 2982 4108 
        #                                    2542 2542 (?)
        #4125 3052 
        #                                    3879 3879  (#8831472)
        #3782  
        #                                    3189 3189 (?)
        #4488   
        #                                    4161 4161  (8834556)
        #2987  3128

Comment: @ABCDF 「番号に当てはまる番号が２個ある」という意味がよくわかりません。変数 `line` 内に 2箇所？ "8831472" を持つデータが 2行以上？ … 元の質問の範囲に外れていなければ, 質問に追加する形で情報載せるとよいかもです

Comment: 度々使用方法まで教えていただき申し訳ないです　　ありがとうございます　　範囲から外れてはいないと思うのですが追加してみました　見ていただければ嬉しいです

Answer (score 0):

テストデータがあると確認しやすいかな、と思いまして少し調べてみると以下のサイトにありました。

[ダウンロード情報｜社会保険診療報酬支払基金](https://www.ssk.or.jp/seikyushiharai/rezept/hokenja/download/index.html)

ここから以下のデータをダウンロードしました。

電子レセプトのCSV情報及びレセプト電子データのサンプルデータ

令和2年4月診療分 医科:18件(ZIP:930KB)

中に入っている CSV ファイルを取り出して、ファイル名を `RECEIPTC.UKE` に変更します。Pandas の `read_csv()` を使用して読み込みます。

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('RECEIPTC.UKE', 'r', encoding="shift-jis")
                         :

pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 123, saw 2
```

………なんと、エラーが発生してしまいました。原因はカラム数が不揃いなためです。仕方ないので読み方を変えます。

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('RECEIPTC.UKE', sep='\n', header=None, prefix='X', encoding="shift-jis")
df = df.X0.str.split(',', expand=True).fillna('')

print(df)

      0   1  2   3                                                 4   ... 46 47 48 49 50
0     2   1  0  MN                                         910000041  ...               
1     1   2  0  IR                                                 1  ...               
2     1   3  0  RE                                                 9  ...               
3     1   4  0  HO                                          06132013  ...               
4     1   5  0  GR                                                09  ...               
...  ..  .. ..  ..                                               ...  ... .. .. .. .. ..
998   2  11  1  EX                                                    ...               
999   2  12  1  EX                                                    ...               
1000  2  13  0  RC          Ver00001bd39c87bcce59458fa26da72e53ef72c  ...               
1001  2  14  1  RC  Ver000017f93222aded463b40f8281c6d95aadcd37d7ca44  ...               
1002  

[1003 rows x 51 columns]
```

> イメージとしては、SYがある行 且つ その行に AかBかCかDかEの病名がある患者番号を出力するというのが目的です。

```py
# 識別情報が SY の行数
print(len(df[df[3]=='SY']))
242

# 抽出したい傷病情報リスト
SVs = ("1509003", "8841698", "2500015", "1509003", "8842624")

# 抽出条件式
condition = (df[3] == 'SY') & (df[4].isin(SVs))

# 抽出(患者番号が何列目にあるのか分からないので全体を表示)
print(df[condition])

#
     0   1  2   3        4         5  6     7  8   9  ... 
5    1   6  0  SY  1509003  20151102  1           01  ... 
6    1   7  0  SY  8841698  20151110  1               ... 
7    1   8  0  SY  2500015  20151110  1               ... 
8    1   9  0  SY  1509003  20151217  1  8048     01  ... 
9    1  10  0  SY  8842624  20151222  1           01  ... 
310  1   8  0  SY  2500015  20190121  1               ... 
546  1   8  0  SY  2500015  20190121  1               ... 
761  1   9  0  SY  8841698  20190801  1               ... 
806  1  10  0  SY  8842624  20121203  1               ... 
877  1  21  0  SY  2500015  20190424  1               ... 

[10 rows x 51 columns]
```

Comment: (お名前をsuggest？するのですが何故か付きません；；）コメントありがとうございます　　　CSVデータも調べていだきありがとうございます　pandasをしっかり使えば、このような方法もあるのですね　　この方法も是非使用したいです　私もすぐにコードを書けるように精進したいです　ありがとうございます

Comment: さん　別スレッドでありがとうございました　　pandasでも試行錯誤したことがあるのですが　pandasで再度metropolis   さんの答えを参考にしてみます　ありがとうございます